# How to find the area between 3 curves?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, regions

I have three equations: $y=3/x$, $y=12x$, and $y=x/12$, $x>0$. I am not sure how to go about integrating an equation once I find the intersections. Do I need multiple integrals?

Comment: Are you using software _Mathematica_? This **SE** site is about _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 14):

The region within the three curves can be plotted and its area determined using Mathematica's geometric capabilities.

```
RegionPlot[y < 3/x && y < 12 x && y > x/12, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, 
    PlotPoints -> 200, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

and integrate its area by

```
Area[ImplicitRegion[y < 3/x && y < 12 x && y > x/12, {x, y}]]

(* Log[1728] *)
```

Answer (score 7):

When you use Mathematica, you could start with a plot like this

`Plot[{3/x, 12 x, x/12}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]`

Then you can see where the area is which you should integrate.

And by using 
`Solve[3/x == 12 x, x]`, `Solve[12 x == x/12, x]` and `Solve[x/12 == 3/x, x]` 
you can calculate the three intersections which are 0, 0.5 and 6.

The area between the curves can then be calculated by

`Integrate[12 x, {x, 0, 0.5}] + Integrate[3/x, {x, 0.5, 6}] - Integrate[x/12, {x, 0, 6}]`.

I hope this help.